# Persistent live-usb stuck at Checking Disks

Tags: live-usb, persistence, disk-check

So I have a persistent live-usb that gets stuck at boot during the disk check. It won't let me skip with ctrl+c. The only solution I've found is to edit the grub.cfg file to skip the disk check but I can't do that until I can boot to it. I've tried to find the file with a separate install or from the regular live mode but I can't seem to locate the persistent files on the drive. What should I do? Where are the persistent files stored so I can edit the cfg file?

Comment: If you make the persistent live drive with [mkusb's dus-persistent tool](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb), there is no checking disks at boot. - You can also edit the `grub.cfg` file: add the boot option `fsck.mode=skip` on the line starting with `linux`. This file can be located in different places, depending on how the persistent live drive was created, but usually you find it as `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` when the persistent live system is running.

Comment: That's the problem. I can't run it because it gets stuck at the disk check. I believe I used mkusb to make the drive but that was like 2 years ago and I did not make use of the option to disable it

Comment: The disk is probably corrupted. Make another one. You might be able to use a live session from the second disk to recover any files on the original.

Comment: Nmath may be right. Did you make any [backups](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent#Backup_and_restore_of_persistent_overlay_data)? If not, you can probably boot from another Ubuntu system and recover files from the partition for persistence labeled `casper-rw` if old. or `writable` if new (the label depends on the version of Ubuntu). Please notice that it is important to have **only one persistent live drive connected at boot**, otherwise they can get mixed up and corrupted.

Comment: That is unfortunate. I don't really have many files on it but the issue is I spent an inordinate amount of time bringing it up to parity with a full install. I fought with that thing to add every feature and package and their dependencies for like a month in my free time

Comment: Now there are a couple of options: 1. Make a new persistent live drive and tweak it; 2. Make an installed system in a external drive (USB pendrive or USB SSD) -- In both cases, it is important to create a backup, or even better a regular backup routine, so that you can restore the system, if/when something nasty happens. Backup is extra important with external systems, because they are more sensitive to corruption that internal systems. -- Finally, you are not alone, most of us have learned the hard way how important it is with a regular backup routine (maybe once a week).